# Hide Addthis button in category list (blog layout) in joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0, addthis

I'm using Joomla 3 an I install Addthis plugin to show addthis button on the top of each article,

But I need to hide it in article list only (I'm using category blog layout), And leave it inside the article page .

I try to add this line to blog.php but nothing change:

```
addthis_toolbox.addthis_default_style {display: none !important;}
```

But nothing changed.

Can anyone give any advice .
Thanks.

Comment: I try to add this code to the plugin:

<style type="text/css">
.item .addthis_toolbox.addthis_default_style {
display: none !IMPORTANT;
}
</style>

but this disable addthis in everywhere :-\ :(

Answer (score 0):

I´m using 3.5.1 and AddThisPlugin-2.0.2.
Open addthis.php to notepad++ or similar and on line 57: `$this->appendAddThisScript();`

wrap it like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$view = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
if ($view !== "category") {
$this->appendAddThisScript();
}
```

This one makes it conditional to load only if something else than category view. With CSS display: none; it is still loading all the scripts.